# Angular code working in Visual Studio but not in IIS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have created a project with MVC and Angular.js
My app works fine from visual studio.
But when I Publish it in IIS i get error messages in console saying there are some issues in angular.min.js file.

Console error is :  Unknown provider: nProvider <- n

I have tried to publish code both in debug and release modes. Nothing is working.
It is working fine from the visual studio.

[[image: I Here is the image of console errors1]

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and found that when I try to access the angular.min.js directly in the browser file then it was giving an error,

```
base_url/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js
HTTP Error 404.8 - Not Found
```

The "request filtering module" is a feature in IIS 7 and above. When IIS rejects a request based on this feature, the error code logged is 404.8. This feature allows you to define which segments are "Servable".

If this is the error you are facing then follow these steps to resolve it.

1. Open the IIS Manager on your Windows server.
2. Click the website on which you need to modify your settings.
3. Double click "Request Filtering" from the IIS section and go to the "Hidden Segments" tab.
4. Check whether the folder containing (node_modules) angular.min.js which you are trying to access is under the "Hidden Segments".
5. If it is present, right-click the particular folder and then remove it.